# Unable to install MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, installation

I am attempting to install asp.net MVC 3 to use with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I try to install from `AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe`. The install log shows this:

> MSI (s) (08:E4) [00:22:35:745]: Product: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 -- A
>   later version of Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 is already installed. Setup
>   will now exit.
>
> A later version of Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 is already installed. Setup
>   will now exit.

I have MVC 2 installed (it came with VWD 2010). I do not see MVC3 or MVC4 in installed programs list. I don't have NuGet installed. How could I manage to install it?

Comment: When you go to New Project, under the C Sharp -> Web template section, you don't see MVC 3 as an available choice?

Comment: @Eckert No, I do not.

Comment: Try [MVC 3 Download](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) or install the Microsoft Web Platform Instaler and get MVC 3 through it.

Comment: @Eckert That was my first attempt and it failed as well. I managed to solve the issue by downloading the standalone mvc3+tools installer exe, unzipping it and running the 1.6meg msi installer directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently had a corrupted installation. I was unable to see MVC3 installed in control panel and I was unable to see it in visual studio, but the installer detected it anyway.

I managed to install it by unzipping the installer exe and then running `aspnetmvc3vwd2010tools.msi` from within it directly. I found that it was the correct msi by accident. Running setup from with in it failed consistently.